# Where were we taught the mechanics needed for Swamp Yellow Puzzle 4?

Tags: the-witness

Last night I finally got to the point where I just had to cheat in The Witness. The answer (provided by [IGN's Walkthrough](http://m.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Swamp)) sent me through the roof. Where were we taught that we could manipulate the shapes in this manner?

My spouse pointed out that Green Puzzle 3-2 (using IGN's numbering system) manipulates the shapes in this way, which could be true, but could also not be true if you just place them on top of each other, which is how I imagined it when I solved it. Am I just not seeing it right?

Comment: 1. This is a Q&A site, not a forum - there's no answerable question here? and 2. There are no new mechanics introduced in that puzzle, so I don't know what you mean by "manipulate the shapes in this way".

Comment: Pretty sure its a question. Show me where we are taught this mechanic. I'm totally open to the idea that I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution to that puzzle *(hover to see spoilers)*:

> [image: Yellow-4 solution]

You haven't explained what *"manipulate shapes in this manner"* means, but there are no new mechanics introduced in that puzzle:

- **Blocks can move around inside the space**: Green 2-6, 2-7; Red 1-1 thru 1-4, 1-6; etc.
- **Tilted blocks can rotate**: Green 3-5 thru 3-8; Yellow 1 thru 4
- **Blocks with holes can overlap/be filled**: Green 3-1 thru 3-4; Yellow 2

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! For some reason my brain was unable to rotate the 3-block triangle shapes the way you drew them. I knew you could overlap them, but after seeing the answer in the tutorial, I thought the developers just straight up manipulated the shape of the shapes (i.e. changed the triangle shapes into three-block L shapes) to solve it. But I see it now. And my faith is restored.

Comment: Pieces displayed at an angle can be rotated (but pieces displayed straight up and down must be traced as they are).